# What is the term for a name converted to a URL parameter?

Tags: url, terminology, urldecode

I want to learn what is it called -if there is any name for it- when you convert a name to a URL parameter, like, `urldecode()` in PHP.

Suppose in my database, I list some TV series, and one row is for *The Big Bang Theory*, I usually do it like:

```
title                  name
------                 -----
The Big Bang Theory    the-big-bang-theory
```

So is there a specific name for the second column, named "name"?

I remember something like "slug" or "stub" from one of the CMS’.

Answer (score 2):

```
http://example.com/articles/the-big-bang-theory?revision=1
```

- [Path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3):
  `/articles/the-big-bang-theory`
- Path segments/subcomponents:
  `articles`
  `the-big-bang-theory`
- [Slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug) (not a technically defined term):
  `the-big-bang-theory`

---

```
http://example.com/articles/427ds17v223?revision=1
```

- [Path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3):
  `/articles/427ds17v223`
- Path segments/subcomponents:
  `articles`
  `427ds17v223`
- [Slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug) (not a technically defined term):
  *none*, or `427ds17v223`

---

There are various definitions for the term *slug*. Some may always call the **last path segment** a *slug*, some may use this term only if the **last path segment is human-readable/understandable**.